# How to change tibble's cells by quasiquotation in R

Tags: r

I have a tibble with only one row:

```
library('tibble')

df <- tibble(date=2019,
             first_col=20,
             second_col=30,
             third_col=40)
```

And I have the key as a string, for example:

```
key <- 'first'
```

Now I can get value of first cell from my tibble using expression:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0('df$',key,'_col')))
# 20
```

But I can't rewrite this cell:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0('df$',key,'_col'))) <- 40

#Error in eval(parse(text = paste0("df$", target, "_col"))) <- 40 : 
 target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `!!` to evaluate column name and `:=` to assign the value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate(!!paste0(key,"_col") := 40)

#   date first_col second_col third_col
#  <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
#1  2019       40         30        40
```

Comment: @JackPo `:=` is like `=` but it allows to evaluate expressions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
      mutate(!! str_c(key, "_col") := 40)
```